# jQuery not scrolling to anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't seem to get this functioning the way that I want. I want a user to click a link, in this case `Learn More` then open a tab and scroll down the page to where that tab is. I have the functionality of opening the tab working but it will not scroll. The only time I can get it to actually scroll is to copy:

`jQuery(document).scrollTop( jQuery("#" + descriptionID).offset().top );`

into chrome's console and activate it. Below is the code in its entirety:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".learnMore", function() {
    description = jQuery("a.ui-tabs-anchor:contains('Description')").parent().index();
    descriptionID = jQuery("a.ui-tabs-anchor:contains('Description')").attr('id');
    jQuery(".ui-widget").tabs("option", "active", description);
    jQuery(document).scrollTop( jQuery("#" + descriptionID).offset().top );
});
```

Here is a link to a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o2whkLyu/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because when you click the link, it's triggering the hash change.  Because there is no anchor to go to, it scrolls to top *after* you call `scrollTop`.  Adding `return false;` to the end of your click event or adding `e.preventDefault();` for more modern browsers should correct the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/dL41forj/

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".learnMore", function() {
    ...
    return false;
});
```

or

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".learnMore", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

Comment: quick question is there a preferred method, using `return false` or `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Typically I would prefer using `e.preventDefault()`, as it can be placed anywhere within the code. For `return false`, it will simply stop the function from executing, thereby nullfying/skipping all lines of code underneath it (within the same function).

Comment: in most cases I would say no.  Calling `preventDefault()` has the added benefit of being detectable with `isDefaultPrevented()`.  but I kind of prefer the `preventDefault` approach out of preference.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a timeout and targeting the body also works: http://jsfiddle.net/o2whkLyu/1/

```
$(document).on("click", ".learnMore", function() {
    description = jQuery("a.ui-tabs-anchor:contains('Description')").parent().index();
    descriptionID = jQuery("a.ui-tabs-anchor:contains('Description')").attr('id');
    jQuery(".ui-widget").tabs("option", "active", description);
    setTimeout (function(){
        $('body').scrollTop( $("#" + descriptionID).offset().top );}, 20);
});
```